# How do I pass a PersistentStringParameter to a parametrized Jenkins job in a build step?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parametrized Jenkins pipeline job that takes a `PersistentStringParameter` (from the [Persistent Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Persistent+Parameter+Plugin)). I am starting this job from another job, using a [build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) that looks like this:

```
build(wait: true, propagate: false, job: 'my_job', parameters: job_params)
```

Here `job_params` is a [List](https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Lists) of the form

```
job_params = [string(name: 'PARAM_NAME', value: '42')]
```

Jenkins complains a bit about the fact that a `PersistentStringParameter` is expected, but I am passing a `string`:

```
The parameter 'PARAM_NAME' did not have the type expected by my_job. Converting to Persistent String Parameter.
```

Is there any way I can avoid this warning? How do I put a `PersistentStringParameter` in `job_params`?

Comment: In my_job, try to get the type of the parameter like this: `echo params.PARAM_NAME.getClass()`. Then try to specify the parameter class like this: `job_params = [[$class: 'CLASS_NAME', name: 'PARAM_NAME', value: '42']]`

Comment: @zett42 if you turn this into an answer I will accept it